Youtube API failed to fetch
My function will not fetch no matter what, and just for searching I dont think oauth is required. I just want to get json of videos from a keyword search
function search() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchInput').value
    if (input === "" || input === null || input === undefined || input.length < 3) {
        console.log('Please provide a valid keyword');
        return;
    }
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    searchByKeyword(input);
}



function searchByKeyword(keyword) {
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=' + maxResults + '&q=' + keyword + '&type=video&key=' + DEVELOPER_KEY;

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            let results = data.items;
            for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                let item = results[i];
                console.log('[%s] Title: %s', item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
        });
}

Tried using axios but can't user outside scripts and require won't work.
Made sure API key was correct
This is for chrome extension so may be more difficult due to their rules on outside scripts, ect.

What happens? What’s in log and network tabs?

"My function will not fetch"... what does it do instead? Do you see anything from any of your console.log() / console.error() logs? Where / how are you calling the searchByKeyword() function? If this is running in the browser, do you see any hints in the dev-tools Network or Console panels?

I get this -
There has been a problem with your fetch operation: TypeError: Failed to fetch
at searchByKeyword (main.js:39:5)
at search (main.js:31:5)
at HTMLButtonElement. (main.js:20:9)

Nothing sent to the youtube api url in network, just to my internal scripts since its a chrome extension
